# How can I improve the time to detect a new Dag on GCP Composer? (Airflow)

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I created a Composer Cluster on GCP (Airflow), It works pretty well but it's slow for the immediate tasks. I created the next DAG in a local file:

```
import datetime
from airflow import models
from pprint import pprint as pp
from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator
import datetime as dt

from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


def create_task_dag(dag_id, schedule, start_date, task_id):

    dag = models.DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        schedule_interval=schedule,
        start_date=start_date
    )

    with dag:
        _operator_name = KubernetesPodOperator(
            task_id='#task_type#-#taskid#',
            name='#task_type#-#taskid#',
            cmds=['bash', '-cx'],
            arguments=["command"],
            env_vars=#env_vars#,
            namespace='default',
            image='image:latest',
            image_pull_secrets="secret",
            image_pull_policy='Always',
            get_logs=True
        )
        _operator_name
        return dag

task_id='#task_type#-#taskid#'
dag_id = 'dag-#task_type#-#taskid#'
schedule = '@once'
start_date = datetime.datetime.now()

globals()[dag_id] = create_task_dag(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    schedule=schedule,
    start_date=start_date,
    task_id=task_id)
```

When I upload that file, it took a long time for running, so, I added `dag_dir_list_interval=1`, it improved but it takes 20-30 seconds to appear on the Airflow's Dashboard and 40-60 seconds to start on Kubernetes.

That means that I need almost one minute to run a Hello world.

Might I have a mistake?

PS: I checked the scheduler and it appears in the pod disk 2-5 seconds later.

Image Version: `composer-1.8.4-airflow-1.10.3`
Cluster: 3 nodes on Kubernetes `n1-standard-1`

Answer (score 0):

This is generally working as intended. If you want to test locally, you might want to install Airflow locally and test out DAG components there. The reason this is *working as intended* is for a few reasons.

1. It takes a little bit of time for Composer to pick up the DAG from Cloud Storage. [As noted in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#data_synchronization) the synchronization is eventual.
2. Airflow is not "the best" at task latency - it's not exceptionally uncommon for operations to take on the order of seconds to complete.

I suspect if you tried a hello world using something like the `BashOperator` it'd be much faster (only the GCS delay.)